# Loading using ajax request - onEachFeature leaflet - multiple requests

Tags: leaflet

Hi I am trying to find out how to add a loading in a ajax call, but there is one issue, in the example below the loader hide on the first request, but I need to hide it only when the last request is made.

onEachFeature/geoJson runs multiple markers on my map, each marker has a unique data, so ajax runs one time for each marker.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

                if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {

                    function getImage(value) {

                        function applyImage(result, resultB) {
                         //do something...
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "libs/php/getImage.php",
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                id: value,
                            },

                            success: function (result) {
                                
                                $("#iframeloading").show();
                                let valueA = result.A;
                                let valueB = result.B
                                applyImage(valueA, valueB)
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                console.log('error');
                            },
                            complete: function() {
       hide goes here but there's no effect...
                            }
                        })
                    };

                    getImage(feature.properties.wikidata)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in my code, just put it before ajax calls, it will apply to every ajax call:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#iframeloading").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#iframeloading").hide();
});
```